# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 + ActiveMQ 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure JMS Transport with ActiveMQ in WSO2 ESB 5.0.0. I have followed the instructions in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configure+with+ActiveMQ with no success.

My ActiveMQ version is 5.10.

When I send a message through the JMS Endpoit I get this error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-10-11 17:42:15,618] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} - Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSOutTransportInfo.createJMSSender(JMSOutTransportInfo.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender.sendMessage(JMSSender.java:135)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportSender.invoke(AbstractTransportSender.java:112)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:297)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:581)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:78)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:512)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:382)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:65)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.TemplateEndpoint.sendMessage(TemplateEndpoint.java:74)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.TemplateEndpoint.send(TemplateEndpoint.java:66)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.ResolvingEndpoint.sendMessage(ResolvingEndpoint.java:74)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.ResolvingEndpoint.send(ResolvingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:121)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:330)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This exception is thrown just when we use XA Transaction. Otherwise it works properly.

Any help?

Comment: please share the proxy and files config.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ActiveMQ 5.10, you need to put in /lib directory to the 
/repository/components/lib directory the following files:

```
activemq-broker-5.10.0.jar
activemq-client-5.10.0.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hawtbuf-1.10.jar
```

Not the files listed in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configure+with+ActiveMQ

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ has a XA connection factory:

Specify: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory

Comment: I guess you hit the nail on the head. It works with no transactions but  it fails when using them. Where should we specify that connection factory? We have tried this endpoint "jms:/SimpleStockQuoteService?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://127.0.0.1:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue" with no effect.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Active MQ version 5.10, you have to add following jars from version 5.8 into $ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib.

- activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar
- activemq-client-5.8.0.jar
- geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
- geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar

And uncomment JMS transport listener and JMS transport receiver in  /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml .

```
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
   <parameter name="myTopicConnectionFactory" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">topic</parameter>
   </parameter>

   <parameter name="myQueueConnectionFactory" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
   </parameter>

   <parameter name="default" locked="false">
       <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
       <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">tcp://localhost:61616</parameter>
       <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
   </parameter>
```

```
<transportSender name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender"/>
```

Then start the server.

You have to check your configurations according to your scenario[1].

When ESB sends to a jms endpoint sample code will be as follows:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="StockQuoteProxy" transports="http">
 <target>
    <inSequence>
        <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="jms:/SimpleStockQuoteService?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;                 java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/> 
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    </target>
    <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
   </proxy>
```

Your error indicating about issue with a JMS sender. Specially check your configurations within axis2 and the proxy configs that you define jms endpoint.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/JMS+Usecases